# OneNote 2010 remove hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I'm using MS one note 2010.

In my note, I want to store a note containing `\\` string, e.g.

```
net use \\192.168.0.111\C$ SomePassword /user:SomePC\Administrator
```

OneNote thinks that `\\` and everything after that is a hyperlink.

How can I remove the hyperlink?

When I right click and select "Remove link" it disappears.
However the effect is only temporary, the link is restored after e.g. re-opening one note.

How can I make it gone forever?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. It's OK if the solution will disable automatic link creation in all my notes.
I'm comfortable pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> every time I do need a hyperlink.

Comment: This issue has not as of yet been corrected in OneNote 2016 either, by the way. Anyway the only way I have found out to disable the automatic hyperlinks in OneNote 2010 is by adding an extra character (such as the pipe-symbol | or backslash \\) to the beginning of the hyperlink (just before the http:// or the two backslashes as in \\192...).

Answer (score 4):

I have found a kludgy workaround that works in OneNote 2016 on Windows; insert an invisible Zero Width Joiner (ZWJ) character between the two forward-slash character. This works even if the URL is prefixed with a protocol such as `http:`

This can be done by typing <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd> and the rest of the URL <sup>[1]</sup>.

This also works to prevent auto-creation of other hyperlinks; For example, insert a ZWJ after typing `www`, then type the <kbd>.</kbd> and the rest of the URL.

[1] Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, type <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> on the numeric keypad, release <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: This is the correct answer, since it doesn't require any macros.  The technique for entering the ZWJ might be different on a Mac, but if you figure out how to enter it, I suspect it would work there also.

Comment: Very old post so I'm not sure this will help, but current versions of OneNote do this automatically (even with a delay after pasting from notepad in a block of text). I have a simpler version of this workaround, which is just to start from the second forward slash after the protocol. It looks like a relative path and ON can't parse it.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use Macro to remove and clean hyperlinks.

Here is the link for that.

http://omeratay.com/onetastic/?r=macroland&id=3CCCF26E44F74EF49E102FEE9A64799F

It looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Despite existing in every other microsoft product, this UX feature doesn't exist in OneNote (2010 nor 2013, which I just verified as being absent as well)

both these MS forum sources note that this feature doesn't exist, but do suggest pasting from MS word, which may eliminate your problem (despite being overly complicated)

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-onenote/how-can-i-turn-off-automatic-hyperlinks-in-onenote/0bddf372-9275-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9d409c67-875b-4b92-80bd-24b67f6e05af/onenote-2010-how-to-remove-links

Hope that helps, sorry there isn't a better answer.

P.S. A workable solution would be like @Cricrazy describes, and make a macro to remove hyperlinks with a hotkey after setting up the macro to do so.

Comment: I just noticed this is over 2 years old, I apologize for the likely useless late answer. Hopefully this helps web searchers at least. I would have thought MS could have included this feature in 2013 after all the negative feedback on this feature, but alas, we are stuck with hyperlinks being autogenerated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *File → Options → Advanced*, unselect *Include link to source when pasting from the web*.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a Zero Width Space Invisible Character between the slashes works well for me in OneNote for Windows 10. Type 200b then press Alt-X.

[UniCode ZWS on FileFormat.Info](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm)

I'm mentioning this because Alt-8203 doesn't work on the Windows 10 version of OneNote; it inserts a new line instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this better than the answer by Julie from over 4 years ago?

Comment: @DarkDiamond Thanks! Julie's answer doesn't work on OneNote for Windows 10 because Alt-8203 inserts a new line. A lot of people will be using OneNote for Windows 10 these days rather than OneNote 2016. Also Julie's answer refers to forward slashes but the original poster asked for a solution for backslashes.

Comment: @BananaJack ok, that is a good reason to post a new answer. Maybe it would be helpful to add this to your answer as not everybody will read the comments.

Comment: Thanks @DarkDiamond - good advice! I've now done that.